# Consider the group homomorphism $\phi:M_2(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $\phi(A)=\mathrm{trace}(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Consider the group homomorphism $\phi:M_2(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $\phi(A) = \text{trace}(A)$. The kernel of $\phi$ is isomorphic to which of the following groups?

a) $M_2(\mathbb{R})/ \{A \in M_2(\mathbb{R}):\phi(A)=0\}$

b) $\mathbb{R}^2$

c) $\mathbb{R}^3$

d) $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: Try and write out a generic matrix of trace zero.

Comment: I think option a is correct?

Comment: No, please think again. That is the quotient over the kernel.

Comment: Kernel of ϕ is the collection of those matrices whose trace are zero,

Comment: I recommend consulting the help menu for advice on formatting math on this site.

Comment: i can not understand...how to solve the problem..plz help me

Comment: Find a nice formula that parametrizes all traceless matrices.

Comment: If $\begin{bmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix} $ has trace zero, what's the relation between $a$ and $d$? How many parameters are left?

Comment: a+d=0 and there are 2 parameters left

Comment: $a+d=0$ eliminates only one parameter.

Comment: yes..a+d=0 eliminates one parameter then there are total 3 parameter

Answer (score 3):

The map is linear and surjective. The rank-nullity theorem says
$$
\dim M_2(\mathbb{R})=\dim\ker\phi+1
$$
because the image of $\phi$ has dimension $1$.

Therefore , one of the choices is obvious. However, if you are really dealing with *group* homomorphisms, then only one choice is excluded, namely the only group that has non trivial torsion elements. (Thanks to Omnomnomnom who drew more attention to the question's formulation.)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Added, thanks. But they're free $\mathbb{Q}$-modules with a basis of the same uncountable cardinality.

Comment: @Ben I have a query, how $\mathbb{R}$and $\mathbb{R^3}$ can be isomorphic as both have different dimensions?

Comment: @egreg I get it now, thanks for clarifying

Comment: @mathstudent They are isomorphic as $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces (assuming choice, of course), because they have the same uncountable cardinality, so the same dimension over $\mathbb{Q}$.